# Wifi not working Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, server, 14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server on my machine. Its network connection will be through wifi. However, my Wifi connection is not working.

My /etc/network/interfaces file is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
pre-up /etc/init.d/wpa.sh start
post-down /etc/init.d/wpa.sh stop
```

When I run the command "iwlist wlan0 scan" it returns:

```
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down
```

In the syslog I see:

```
May  9 17:59:15 andyhyatt-server kernel: [  361.085482] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: fail to load firmware brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw
```

This leads me to believe that it is a driver issue. I checked in /lib/firmware/brcm/ for bcm43xx-0.fw, but the only driver in that directory is bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin, which makes sense because I am on a Mac Mini mid 2010 (Macmini4,1).

I have a BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n for my network adapter.

Configuring WPA_Supplicant is not my problem, I will get to that after I obtain proper drivers. Also how do i install it.

TL;DR: I need to get a driver for my BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n.

Comment: Cmon guys! Anyone got answers! Please help me with this issue that I am having.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. This guide on [**Installing b43/b43legacy firmware**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#A12.04_.28Precise_Pangolin.29_-_14.04_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) which is listed in the official Ubuntu page should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I downloaded the deb for the firmware-brcm80211 package. You can not use apt-get because it is on the Debian APT repository.

http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-brcm80211_0.36+wheezy.1_all.deb

This can be done with the `wget` command.

Then, simply use `dpkg install firmware-brcm80211_0.36+wheezy.1_all.deb` to install the package. Reboot, and Wifi should be working for your BRCM43224!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in ubuntu 14.4
for resolve this problem you have install network manager
type following commands

```
sudo network-manager-gnome
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
sudo nm-connection-editor
```

open the tab menu update password
Enjoy !! This is really helps you :)

[click Here](http://php999.blogspot.in/2015/01/ubuntu-1404-connect-to-wifi-button-not.html)

Comment: I don't use a desktop envoirnment, so everything must be command line. Thank you for the reply though.